# Adding a convenience initializer for a core data Entity

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

In Swift 3/Xcode 8, how do you create a convenience initializer for a Core Data entity? Right now I have a normal class and use an convenience initializer to save data from JSON like this:

```
convenience init?(json: [String: Any]) {
    let id = json["id"] as! Int
    let title = json["title"] as! String
    let subtitle = json["subtitle"] as? String

    self.init(
        anId: id,
        aTitle: title,
        aSubtitle: subtitle,
    )
}
```

Is there a simple way to add something like this to a Core Data defined entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, in any case you have to call the designated initializer of `NSManagedObject / NSEntityDescription`.

Something like this:

```
class Foo: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var title: String
    @NSManaged var subtitle: String?
    @NSManaged var id: Int32

    class func create(in context: NSManagedObjectContext, from json: [String: Any]) -> Foo {
        let foo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Foo", into: context) as! Foo
        foo.title = json["title"] as! String
        foo.subtitle = json["subtitle"] as? String
        foo.id = json["id"] as! Int32
        return foo
    }
}
```

`create(in` is a class method, you can call it

```
let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let newItem = Foo.create(in: context, from: jsonDictionary)
```

`appDelegate` is the `AppDelegate` instance, `jsonDictionary` is a `[String:Any]` dictionary.

Comment: I had to do a couple of other things. In the DataModel inspector in the xcdatamodel I had to set codegen to Category/Extension and I had to add `@objc(Foo)` above the class definition.  And also obviously import CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend your class with a convenience initialiser:

```
convenience init(
  context moc: NSManagedObjectContext, 
  json: [String: Any]
) {
    self.init(context: moc)

    id = json["id"] as? Int
    title = json["title"] as? String
    subtitle = json["subtitle"] as? String
}
```